# jQuery, return previous properties to elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

when I click on the button, I create new properties for the elements. How can I return the previous properties to the elements?
I have a list of div's. Clicking on which opens another div. I thought it would be good to use 'this'. But I couldn't implement it, please help!
I have a lot of div's, with different classes and id. So I can't just refer to the div.

I used the toggle function, but the problem is that there is animation there. If I put the argument '0' before the function, then I simply do not return the previous properties

if(count==2) {count==0} -- The function of opening and closing div when pressed, please comment on your answer, I am not an expert.

```js
<script>
            let count =0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    
      $("#btn1faq").click(function() {
        count++;
    
    
        $("#hiddencase1").toggle(0, "linear",function() {
            if(count==2) {
                count=0;
    
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "0em");
        $(".daunstr").css("left", "40em");
        $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "40em");
        $(".upstr").hide();
        $(".daunstr").show();
    
            }
        });
    
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "-4.9em");
        $(".daunstr").css("left", "45em");
    
        $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "44em");
    
        $("#dstr1").hide();
    
            $(".upstr").css("left", "45em");
        $(".upstr").css("top", "3em");
        $(".upstr").show();
    
      });
    
    
      $("#btn2faq").click(function() {
        $("#hiddencase2").toggle();
    
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "-4.9em");
        $(".daunstr").css("left", "45em");
    
        $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "44em");
    
        $("#dstr2").hide();
    
            $(".upstr2").css("left", "45em");
        $(".upstr2").css("top", "3em");
        $(".upstr2").show();
    
      });
    
      $("#btn3faq").click(function() {
          $("#hiddencase3").toggle();
    
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "-4.9em");
        $(".daunstr").css("left", "45em");
    
        $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "44em");
    
        $("#dstr3").hide();
    
            $(".upstr3").css("left", "45em");
        $(".upstr3").css("top", "3em");
        $(".upstr3").show();
      });
    
      $("#btn4faq").click(function() {
    
         $("#hiddencase4").toggle();
    
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "-4.9em");
        $(".daunstr").css("left", "45em");
    
        $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "44em");
    
        $("#dstr4").hide();
    
            $(".upstr4").css("left", "45em");
        $(".upstr4").css("top", "3em");
        $(".upstr4").show();
      });
    
      $("#btn5faq").click(function() {
         $("#hiddencase5").toggle();
    
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("position", "relative");
        $(".afterjsdiv1").css("left", "-4.9em");
        $(".daunstr").css("left", "45em");
    
        $("div.afterjsdiv1 > .hrdivdownS").css("width", "44em");
    
        $("#dstr5").hide();
    
            $(".upstr5").css("left", "45em");
        $(".upstr5").css("top", "3em");
        $(".upstr5").show();
      });  
    
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: _"How can I return the previous properties to the elements?"_ - by _setting_ them again, same way as it worked with the new values. Of course you would have a lot less work to do in that regard, if you stopped manipulating inline styles (considered back practice for multiple reasons), and added/removed a class on the element(s) in question instead, so that different styling from your stylesheet could apply based on that class.

Comment: why don't you use `addClass()` instead of `css()`  !?